# jquery empty - remove html tag if no contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**jquery empty** - remove html tag if no contents

How to remove html tag if it does not contain text or content.

if using `<p></p>` code is working,
but
if using

```
<p>

</p>
```

The code is not successful

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $('#demo p:empty').remove();
    });
});
```

**html**

```
<p>

</p>
==================================
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
  $('#demo p:empty').remove();
    });
});
```

```css
  p {
    background:red;
    color:white;
    height:20px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>demo</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
</head> 
<body>
  
<button>Run</button> 
<div id='demo'>
  <p>
  
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum .....
  </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: What could possibly be within the <p></p>?

Comment: Just remove space from your <p> tag or before removing trim the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $('#demo p').filter(function() {
      return $(this).html().trim().length == 0
    }).remove();
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>demo</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <button>Run</button>
  <div id='demo'>
    <p>

    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum .....
    </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

1. Use filter() with html() and trim()
2. trim() to remove spaces

Comment: @SisiSajah glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#demo p').each(function(){
 if(!$(this).text() || !$(this).text().trim())
   $(this).remove();
})
```